# Authorization - GetRolesForUser always empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, authorization, roles

I'm using custom login validation in .NET MVC 4 application. But I'm unable to implement Role Authorization via Web.config file.

I have tried as follows:

```
if(loginvalid)
{
    var claimsIdentity = new Claims.ClaimsIdentity(
        new[] 
            { 
                new Claims.Claim(Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "username"),
                new Claims.Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),
                new Claims.Claim(Claims.ClaimTypes.Name,"username"),
                new Claims.Claim(Claims.ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"),
            },
            "CustomApiKeyAuth"
            );

    var principal = new Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { claimsIdentity });

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

    var test1 = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

    // here roleNames variable is always empty.
    string[] roleNames = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
}
```

In the above code the `roleNames` variable is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

And the Web.config code:

```
<location path="token.axd"> 
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="admin"/> 
            <deny users="*"/> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```